# Should I peel Boskoop apples for a pie?

Tags: pie, apples

We have the question [about peeling apples for a pie](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/apple-pie-peel-or-not), and the accepted answer is "depends on the apple".

I seldom make desserts involved baked apples, so I am not well versed in the baking cultivars. A seller recommended [Boskoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belle_de_Boskoop) for pies and baking in general, and I bought the apples, but I did not think of asking how thick their skin is.

Are Boskoop the type of apple which has a thick, unpleasant skin after baking, or does it have a soft skin? Also, how likely is it to fall apart if baked after peeling?

Comment: With respect to skin thickness and peeling, a more general question would be simply how to tell from slicing or biting into any type of apple. Of course, that still leaves your specific second question about standing up to cooking.

Comment: Belle de Boskoop are just fantastic. I always peeled them before baking and they hold together really well. Since I never even considered baking them with the peel I can't provide a complete answer.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbach That's still half an answer, probably worth posting... so is whatever rumtscho did!

Comment: @Jefromi A little research shows me that opinion on the internet is not always with me on this point, so I ought to find some way to back up my facts before I post. I'll do some comparative testing if I can get hold of some Boskoop.

Answer (score 3):

My parents have a Boskoop tree in their garden. I would probably peel the apples before baking them into a pie, but it wouldn't be impossible to not peel them.

The skin is thicker than most red/yellow apples but not as hard as a Granny Smith's, say. When I lived in the Netherlands, if I bought Boskoop (or Goudreinette, as they're commonly called there) in the store, the skin would be a little thinner than from my parents' tree (maybe because the conditions are not as carefully controlled as with professional growers?), but the statement above still holds.

<sup>Boskoop apples are one of the foods I miss from home, living in Canada now. Sniff.</sup>

Comment: In Boskoop are in a group of apples that are also termed "Lederapfel" ("leather apple"), which means the skin can be quite tough, even after cooking. So yes to peeling them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried googling about the apple (never heard of it before) and from what I read I don't think you'll have to peel it.

- http://www.specialtyproduce.com/produce/Belle_de_Boskoop_Apples_4444.php
  It talks about slicing and then baking, no peeling mentioned.
- http://www.orangepippin.com/apples/belle-de-boskoop
- http://forums2.gardenweb.com/forums/load/fruit/msg1117240031249.html
- http://cookingthecity.wordpress.com/tag/boskoop/

Comment: I've edited your two answers together and fixed some things up. To make this a better answer, you might want to summarize what all the links say, not just the first one.